# dbExpress driver for Microsoft Access

Tags: delphi, ms-access, driver, dbexpress

being a dbExpress newbie I wonder if there is a dbExpress driver for Microsoft Access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the only way to connect to Access is by using ADO. (TADOConnection).

Comment: Isn't that the opposite of the question?

Answer (score 3):

I have had good results using the open source dbxoodbc driver for dbExpress.

The download has several demo projects that use access databases, so you should be able to get up and running in no time.

You can find it at http://sourceforge.net/projects/open-dbexpress/

I have only tried it with older versions of access, so I can't say for certain that it will work with office 2007 or newer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use TADOConnection, i havn't been able to find a 3rd party driver which supports the new dbexpres

Answer (score 0):

dbExpress does not support msAccess natively,

But a quick google search gives a long list of drivers. Both free and paid.